# Blender Physics - Keep plane from falling over?

Tags: animation, mesh, physics

So In blender, I have a plane with rigid body physics applied to it. I also have a wind force to lift up the plane, and its force strength is animated so the plane gets lifted up, and then falls back down onto the floor. But because the plane is on its edge, it starts to fall over slightly, then it gets lifted up by the wind force, and when it comes down, it topples over. I need it to stay on its side, and friction isn't helping at all. Is there a way to keep the plane on its side, maybe through the collisions settings?

Comment: A few thoughts, none I'd call an answer. Give the plane some thickness to stand on?  You could put invisible object on either side of the plane as collision objects so the plane can't fall over. You could add an armature, and not do a physics simulation at all, or add an armature in addition to the wind.